# How to handle NFC On/Off cases?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

My app relies on NFC being on for some functionality. After reading through many StackOverflow posts and documentation, it seems we are unable to programmatically turn NFC on or off.

Due to this, we have to do something like:

```
if (mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    //Do what you would usually plan on doing with NFC.
} else {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("NFC Disabled")
           .setMessage(getString(R.string.nfc_disabled_plea)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
            .setNegativeButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override    
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 }
             }).create().show();
}
```

I'm both new to android development and puzzled. Currently, all of my NFC related code is in the onCreated method of my MainActivity, which will be alive for the duration of the app.

Would the correct way to do this be to package all of that code up into a function, and then call that function in my onResume() function with a check to see if `mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()` is true?

Not sure what the best way to do this is.

Comment: Do you have activities other than MainActivity?

Comment: Yeah, but MainActivity holds the ViewPager with Tabs with Fragments so the majority of the time will be in MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this functionality to be available in all your activities, you could make a class that extends `Activity` that has methods like `isNfcEnabled()` and `showNfcDialog()`. Then, you could make all your activities extend that superclass.

For example:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean isNfcEnabled() {
        // Your logic to determine if NFC is enabled
        return true;
    }

    public void showNfcDialog() {
        // Show your dialog here
    }
}
```

Then, for each of your activities...

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (isNfcEnabled()) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            showNfcDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay. So I would basically check in the onResume if they set it to enabled then, correct?